# Writing sine wave with scipy.io.wavfile.write, and reading it

Tags: python, scipy, wav

I create a sine wave (numpy array with the values of the wave) and write a file with its contents. I play the .wav file and it sounds as expected.

Now I open the same file, I plot it and get a square wave.

Why is this?

```
sampling_rate = 44100


def seno(frequency, duration=0.5, sampling_rate=44100.0):
    return np.array([np.sin(n * 2 * np.pi * frequency / sampling_rate) for n in xrange(int(duration * sampling_rate))]).reshape(-1, 1)

# Example:
write('ejemplo_seno.wav', sampling_rate, seno(1000))
```

This is how I create the file

Comment: works fine for me on Python 3.5

Comment: If it *sounds as expected* but you are having problems while opening and plotting it, maybe the problem is in that step, could you share your code to *open and plotting it*?

Comment: @s0upa1t It works fine for me as well in other computer. Same version of python (2.7) but different IPython notebook... that's strange (one in IPNotebook, the other one in Jupyter).